# Rails search with OR in ActiveRecord::Relation

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

After a very long search I'm finally asking this question:
How do I do OR condition queries with ActiveRecord::Relation in Rails 3.0? Basically I believe it has to do something with scoping and stuff....

Here is what I have:

```
class Practice < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name

  has_and_belongs_to_many :doctors
  has_and_belongs_to_many :services
end

class Doctor < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :first_name, :last_name

  has_and_belongs_to_many :practices
  has_and_belongs_to_many :services
end

class Service < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :about

  has_and_belongs_to_many :practices
  has_and_belongs_to_many :doctors
end
```

What I want to achieve is a form where I can do a search queries and get back ActiveRecord::Relation object(so I can use it with will_paginate and so on) with list of Practices. The query should find any Practice where @practice.name matches query_string OR where @practice.doctors.first_names matches query_string OR where @practice.doctors.last_names matches query_string OR @practice.services.names matches query_string. In other words - lets say query_string matches name of a Service the I would like to get back list of Practices related to this Service. Or if first_name or last_name of a Doctor matches query_string then I get Practices associated to this Doctor/Doctors. And of course good old match by Practice.name too :D

I realize that my has_and_belongs_to_many associations aren't good here, it's just for demonstration purpose but I would be happy to hear if someone can help with migrations and associations for my case.

Thanks.

P.S. as I said I use Rails 3.0 and I believe it has to do something about scopes(but I can be wrong of course). Also I've tried MetaWhere but couldn't make it work.... :(

Comment: Did I hear you say you wanted this in one db query? =P

Comment: Yes and the reason is - I could do something like this and get lets say 3 ActiveRecord::Relation objects back but then when I try to put them together they become an array. As I said I really need it to be ActiveRecord::Relation so I can use it with pagination and other things. P.S. didn't find a way to make a ActiveRecord::Relation object from an array.

Comment: Yeah `Relation`s don't work like db views, an array is an array and it's right there in RAM'd in your face. Check out my answer below, hope it works, or at least gives you a new idea!

Comment: Squeel is the updated form of MetaWhere and should be used for Rails 3.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's see how this turns out:

```
class Practice < ActiveRecord::Base
  class < self
    def by_any_name(param)
      joins(:doctors, :services).
      where(<<-SQL, :name => param)
             doctors.first_name = :name OR
             doctors.last_name  = :name OR
             practices.name     = :name OR
             services.name      = :name
      SQL
    end
  end
end
```

Scopes are *so* last-year.

And some left joins fer ya (needs testing!):

```
joins('LEFT JOIN
         (doctors_practices INNER JOIN doctors
            ON doctors.id = doctors_practices.doctors_id)
          ON doctors_practices.practice_id = practices.id
       LEFT JOIN
         (practices_services INNER JOIN services
            ON services.id = practices_services.service_id)
          ON practices_services.practice_id = practices.id')
```

Sheesh, way past my bedtime.

Comment: Will this give anything back in case I have a practice without any associated doctors or services?
Thanks.

Comment: Nope, only inner joins with this syntax. D'you need a left join or somethin'?

Comment: yeah, I think I need something like left joint because even if I won't find any match in Services or Doctors I still want to get matched stuff from Practices. Or if I have matches in all the tables  then I need all :D So it feels like my big Practice table is on the left and two others on the right side.

Comment: thanks for your help but I get   SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: doctors_practices.practice_id: SELECT     "practices".* FROM       "practices"  LEFT JOIN (ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid)  error with your left joint. Also I don't think I can avoid duplication results with this query, do I need to do something with my migrations?

Comment: You can read the column names from the migrations of your `has_and_belongs_to_many` join tables.

Answer (score 0):

You can dig into ARel
OR --see what I did there :)--
check out the very handy gem squeel, which lets you do exactly what you want with a nice syntax.

https://github.com/ernie/squeel